# Spring context.xml truncate path on windows

Tags: java, spring, tomcat

I have this file context.xml and when I start tomcat I have a error on pat

```
<Context>     
    <Parameter name="log4jConfigLocation" 
        value="file:${catalina.base}\conf\log4j.properties" />
    

  <Parameter name="contextConfigLocation" 
    value="file:${catalina.base}\conf\applicationContext.xml/>
..
...
```

The path of ${catalina.base} for the first  parameter log4jConfigLocation is correct
C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.108  and finally is
C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.108\conf\log4j.properties

The path of ${catalina.base} for the parameter contextConfigLocation is truncate to 'C:\Program' when there is first space

Comment: Which version of Spring are you using? Do you use Spring Boot?

Answer (score 1):

Change catalina home in windows from CATALINA_HOME=c:\Program Files... with a double quote. I.e. CATALINA_HOME="c:\program files...".

Or there is an alternative to use C:\PROGRA~1, which points to Program files, and c:\PROGRA~2 as program files(x86). It's an DOS thing to keep 8 characters maximum. E.g. c:\PROGRA~1\Autocat = "C:\PROGRAM FILES\Autocat"

Comment: The first solution will certainly not work: [`setConfigLocation`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ConfigurableWebApplicationContext.html#setConfigLocation-java.lang.String-) uses a simple _"split by delimiter"_ algorithm without a quoting mechanism. The second one should work. Remark: the OP talks about `CATALINA_BASE`, not `CATALINA_HOME`.

Answer (score 0):

The format of Spring's `contextConfigLocation` context parameter is a list of whitespace (or comma, or semicolon) separated locations. Since the [`ConfigurableWebApplicationContext#setConfigLocation`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ConfigurableWebApplicationContext.html#setConfigLocation-java.lang.String-) method does not have any quoting mechanism:

- first Tomcat expands your value to `file:C:\Program Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.108\conf\applicationContext.xml`,
- then Spring interprets it as two values: `file:C:\Program` and `Files\apache-tomcat-7.0.108\conf\applicationContext.xml`.

A possible solution is to pass the value `file:${catalina.base}\conf\applicationContext.xml` directly to Spring. Tomcat does not have a way to disable variable expansion in its configuration files, but since [Tomcat 7.0.104](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/changelog.html#Tomcat_7.0.104_(violetagg)) you can provide default values for the expansion of **non-existent** variables.

You can therefore use the hack:

```xml
<Context>     
  <Parameter name="contextConfigLocation" 
             value="file:${-:-${catalina.base}}\conf\applicationContext.xml" />
  ...
</Context>
```

which tries to expand the non-existent system property `-` and falls back to the string `${catalina.base}` (unlike Spring, Tomcat does not expand the default value provided).